# EnvironmentObject not found for child Shape in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am encountering the following SwiftUI error with `@EnvironmentObject` when used with a custom `Shape`, :

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type MyObject found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for MyObject may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0
```

It only happens when I use any `Shape` method that returns a new copy of the instance like `stroke()`.

Here is a Swift playground example to reproduce:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var size: Int = 100
}

struct MyShape: Shape {
    @EnvironmentObject var envObj: MyObject

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = Path { path in
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                width: envObj.size, height: envObj.size))
        }
        return path
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyShape().stroke(Color.red) // FAIL: no ObservableObject found
        // MyShape() // OK: it works
    }
}

let view = MyView().environmentObject(MyObject())
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

As it looks like environment field is not copied, I've also tried to do it explicitly like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envObj: MyObject

    var body: some View {
        MyShape().stroke(Color.red).environmentObject(self.envObj)
    }
}
```

It still fails. As a SwiftUI beginner, I don't know whether this is the expected behavior, not inheriting the view hierarchy environment, and how to handle it - other than not using the environment.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem actually is that `.stroke` is called *right after constructor*, so before `environmentObject` injected (you can test that it works if you comment out stroke). But `.stroke` cannot be added *after* environment object injected, because `.stroke` is `Shape-only` modifier.

The solution is to inject dependency during construction as below. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct MyShape: Shape {
    @ObservedObject var envObj: MyObject
...
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envObj: MyObject
    var body: some View {
        MyShape(envObj: self.envObj).stroke(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is indeed how I've fixed it waiting for an answer. It looks like a usual pitfall and I hope there was something else. SwiftUI design looks a bit weak to me on this: you can easily break your app just by adding styles depending on the method you use.